# Populate a WPF Listbox with Images

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to populate a listbox with some images (3 of them), the images are coming from within my application, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I need to know which image is selected so that I can update my app theme accordingly.

I am trying to avoid code behind if I possibly can. TIA

Current xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ThemeListBoxItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTheme, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Style="{DynamicResource ThemeListBox}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="{Binding Theme.PreviewImagePath}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ItemSource Themes:

```
Public ITheme[] Themes => _themeService.Themes;
```

ThemeService:

```
Public ThemeService()
{
   Themes = new[]
   {
      DarkTheme,
      DefaultTheme,
      MonoTheme
   };
}

Public ITheme[] Themes { get; }

    public ITheme DarkTheme { get; } = new Theme("Dark Theme",
                                                 "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/DarkTheme.xaml",
                                                 "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Assets/Media/BG_DarkTheme.png");

    public ITheme MonoTheme { get; } = new Theme("Monochrome Theme",
                                                 "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/MonochromeTheme.xaml",
                                                 "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Assets/Media/BG_Monochrome.png");

    public ITheme DefaultTheme { get; } = new Theme("Light Theme",
                                                    "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Themes/DefaultTheme.xaml",
                                                    "pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Assets/Media/BG_LightTheme.png");
```

Theme:

```
public interface ITheme
{
    string DisplayName { get; }

    string PreviewImagePath { get; }

    string ThemeName { get; }

    string ThemePath { get; }
}

public Theme(string name, string themePath, string previewImagePath)
{
    DisplayName = name;
    PreviewImagePath = previewImagePath;
    ThemePath = themePath;
}
```

Currently, my Listbox is populated with 3 items, but there is no image loaded (Green square indicates SelectedItem):
[image: Screenshot of Listbox, Green square indicates SelectedItem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding Path is incorrect. It should be

```
<Image Source="{Binding PreviewImagePath}"/>
```

because the DataContext of the Image is the associated element from the `Themes` collection, i.e. a `Theme` object.

---

Also make sure that a potential `ControlTemplate` in the `ItemContainerStyle` contains a `ContentPresenter` so that the `ItemTemplate` is actually used.

---

And ensure that the `Build Action` of the image files is set to `Resource`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. 
You know when you stare at something for so long you can't for the life of you spot the issue, this was the case here. Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you should have noticed data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application in debugger.